# How to write validation rule on picklist value

Tags: validation-rule

I have a picklist field called byepass. This Field contains Yes and No.
I have a requirement where " Require Signed date, subscription date , invoice desc when Opportunity stage is closed won and byepass is yes"

I tried this but doesnt work

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName , '8-Closed Won'),
    ISPICKVAL(byepass__c, 'No'),
    OR(
        ISBLANK(Signed_Date__c ),
        ISBLANK( Subscription_Date__c ),
        ISBLANK( Invoice__c )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `byepass__c ='Yes'` instead of `'NO'`.

Your formula will be like below.

```
 AND(

ISPICKVAL(StageName , '8-Closed Won'),

ISPICKVAL(byepass__c, 'Yes'),

OR(

ISBLANK(Signed_Date__c ),

ISBLANK( Subscription_Date__c ),

ISBLANK( Invoice__c ) ) )
```

AND:

> Returns a TRUE response if all values are true; returns a FALSE
> response if one or more values are false.
>
> Use the && (AND) function as an alternative to the operator.
>
> Use:
>
> AND(logical1,logical2,...) and replace logical1,logical2,... with
> the values that you want evaluated.

OR

> Determines if expressions are true or false. Returns TRUE if any
> expression is true. Returns FALSE if all expressions are false.
>
> Use this function as an alternative to the operator || (OR)
>
> Use :
>
> OR(logical1, logical2...) and replace any number of logical
> references with the expressions you want evaluated.

Refer the [Formula Operators and Functions by Context](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5)